# Change excerpt length of first post

Tags: excerpt

I have created a custom excerpt length in my functions.php, I would like to extend this function to increase the excerpt length of the first post in a loop.

**My function at the moment:**

```
/* Change Excerpt length */
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 30;
}
```

**Was thinking of something along these lines**

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    global $post;
    if ($post-> FIRST POST?)
        return 50;
    else
        return 20;
}
```

Is there a way of getting post count from **$post->**?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `current_post` property of the [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) object:

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    global $wp_query; // assuming you are using the main query
    if ( 0 === $wp_query->current_post)
        return 50;
    else
        return 20;
}
```

The function may need further tweaks to avoid interfering with other queries in unintended ways, but that is the basic idea.

Comment: Fantastic, am I right you can apply this to different queries then?

Comment: @James : Yes but you'd have globalize the query variable beforehand. WordPress globalizes `$wp_query` for you. If you need to use this in specific queries there are probably better ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) 
{
    static $instance = 0;
    return ( in_the_loop() && 0 == $instance++ ) ? 50 : 20;
}
```

where we use simple counting inside the loop.